# Getting data out of a callback

Tags: matlab, callback

I would like to receive data out of a callback without using global variables within MATLAB. This is not for GUI programming, but for using a `rossubscriber`. I have tried the following:

```
function [mySub] = myFunction(cloudTopic)
    testHandle.a = 0;
    mySub = rossubscriber(cloudTopic,{@mySub_CB,testHandle}, 'BufferSize', 30);
end

function mySub_CB(src, msg, objHandle)
objHandle.a = objHandle.a + 1
end
```

because I read this on the Mathworks Documentation

> Note: There are other ways to extract information from callback
>   functions besides using globals. For example, you can pass a handle
>   object as additional argument to the callback function. See the
>   Callback Definition documentation for more information about defining
>   callback functions.

Unfortunately, this does not work however. testHandle is not being updated and 1 is constantly displayed. How to do this right? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `testHandle` is a `struct` *not* a [`handle` object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/handle-objects.html) and unlike `handle` objects, `structs` are passed by value not by reference.

Probably your easiest option would be to make `mySub_CB` a *subfunction* of `myFunction` and then it can access and modify variables in the workspace of `myFunction`

```
function [mySub] = myFunction(cloudTopic)
    testHandle.a = 0;
    mySub = rossubscriber(cloudTopic, @mySub_CB, 'BufferSize', 30);

    function mySub_CB(src, msg)
        testHandle.a = testHandle.a + 1
    end

end
```